# Convert Query Using Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select sum(DATEDIFF("D",M.ActiveStart,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0))) as Duration_Days
    , m.HomeBranch, m.LocationName
from AX.Memberships M
where m.ActiveStart < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)
and (M.ActiveEnd > DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) or M.ActiveEnd is null)
group by m.HomeBranch, m.LocationName
```

I tried with CTE but results are different, I think query has some issue. Previous query is simple but I want to convert into CTE tables.

```
with CTE_ABC AS (
    select
        SUM(CASE 
            When m.ActiveStart < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) and (M.ActiveEnd > 
                DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) ,-1) or M.ActiveEnd is null)
            then DATEDIFF(D,M.ActiveStart,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)) else 0 end) as Total_Duration
        , M.HomeBranch
        , M.LocationName
    from AX.Memberships M 
    group by M.HomeBranch, M.LocationName
)
Select Total_Duration
From CTE_ABC
```

Comment: Aside: In spite of Microsoft's confusion, it is a `case` _expression_, not _statement_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the issue:

```
select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) ,-1) --> this is end of the month
```

is different to

```
select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) --> this is start of the month
```

So your query will yield different result.

Your `cte` should look like below so it will have same result on your original query.

```
with CTE_ABC AS (
    select
    SUM(CASE 
        When m.ActiveStart< DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) and (M.ActiveEnd > 
        DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) or M.ActiveEnd is null)
        then DATEDIFF(D,M.ActiveStart,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)) else 0 end) as 
        Total_Duration,
        M.HomeBranch,
        M.LocationName
        from AX.Memberships M 
    group by M.HomeBranch,M.LocationName
)
Select Total_Duration From CTE_ABC
```